# Вывод новостей из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема заключается в том, что из БД выводятся все новости кроме последнего id, в чем проблема?

Comment: Есть же кнопка 101010 для подсветки кода, не извращайтесь с картинками

Comment: И ответ принимается галкой слева от него, не тратьте очки уважения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите первое

```
$showall = mysql_fetch_array($news);
```

Вы читаете первую запись, и начинаете цикл с чтения второй (затриая первую)

Comment: спасибо, всё работает